# PropertyDescriptor and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, propertydescriptor

I'm using `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)` and it returns me all properties and get/set methods for it from base class.

I have base class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string Name
    {
      get => _name;
      set => _name = value;
    }
}
```

Derrived class:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override string Name => "Test";
}
```

When I'm getting info for 'Name' property `PropertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly` equals to 'false', but it should be 'true'.
How can I settup 'PropertyDescriptor' so it would return me data only for derrived class type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get by reflection properties of class ,but not from inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596162/get-by-reflection-properties-of-class-but-not-from-inherited-class)

Comment: @BradleyUffner nope, that's not mine case.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, your are right. Retracting close vote.

Comment: This property is **not** read only. Try to set it - it will work. You're only overriding the getter, not the setter.

Comment: I have just tried, it doesn't set it to new value when I'm calling `PropertyDescriptor.SetValue(PropertyOwner, value);` in case when `PropertyOwner` has type of `Bar`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with inheritance.
The `PropertyDescriptor` object you get **does** describe the `Bar`'s property.

The fact that the `IsReadOnly` flag is `false` has nothing to do with the inheritance. But rather it tells you that the property is **in fact** not read only.

You're maybe asking "But why?"

In your code, you're actually overriding only the `get` accessor of the property. The `set` accessor implementation is just being inherited from the base `Foo` class.

You can easily write something like:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.Name = "dummy";
```

This will compile and internally work too - the `_name` backing field will be set to the value provided.

However, this code is dangerous, since `bar.Name` will always return `"Test"` regardless of what you set via `bar.Name = "string value here"`. Furthermore , this code breaks the Liskov substitution principle, because the behavior of the child class `Bar` is different than the one stated by the public interface of the base class `Foo`.

A **read only** property means that you cannot set it's value, so the compiler wouldn't even allow you to write `bar.Name = "text"`. But it does allow you to do that. The property in your case is not read only, it has a buggy (broken) implementation.

Comment: OK. Let's think that it doesn't readonly than when I call `InstanceOfTypeBar.GetType().GetProperty("Name").CanWrite` should be `true` but in fact it is `false`.

Comment: @Sigin, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140298/strange-effect-with-overridden-properties-and-reflection). Your property is **not** read only, the `CanWrite`'s wrong value is a side effect.

Comment: I understand what do u mean, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Here is decompiled [ReflectPropertyDescriptor](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/7de0d30c7c5ef56ab60fee41fcdb50005d24979a/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/ReflectPropertyDescriptor.cs#L446) which is actually returned from `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)` and as u can see it goes though types and use inheritence to get 'set method'

Comment: @Sigin, so what?